# ssis package default Project variables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I have a dtsx package and I am looking at the xml in notepad++. Here is the part that I have a question about:

```
          <SQLTask:ParameterBinding
            SQLTask:ParameterName="@ExecutionId"
            SQLTask:DtsVariableName="User::ExecutionId"
            SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input"
            SQLTask:DataType="11"
            SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
          <SQLTask:ParameterBinding
            SQLTask:ParameterName="@LogPackage"
            SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::PackageName"
            SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input"
            SQLTask:DataType="16"
            SQLTask:ParameterSize="50" />
          <SQLTask:ParameterBinding
            SQLTask:ParameterName="@LogTask"
            SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::TaskName"
            SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input"
            SQLTask:DataType="16"
            SQLTask:ParameterSize="50" />
          <SQLTask:ParameterBinding
            SQLTask:ParameterName="@LogTypeId "
            SQLTask:DtsVariableName="$Project::BASE_LogTypeInfoId"
            SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input"
            SQLTask:DataType="11"
            SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
```

I get that System::PackageName and System::TaskName are both system variables, and I can see where ExecutionId is defined later in the package:

```
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{520609F2-57D5-4619-BD9D-6D39E42CFA7E}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="ExecutionId">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
```

However i do not see anywhere that BASE_LogTypeInfoId is declared or defined in the package and I was wondering if there are default variables available in the "Project" namespace or if this is a busted package.

Comment: Could it be a project parameter? rather then a package variable ?  I know system:: and user:: are package variables.